# redirect to a Django url in another app using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, django

Right now I have two apps in the project, here is the project structure:
[image]

The current function being called is in chess1 and I want to redirect to a url in Chess_Django. My url in Chess_Django/urls.py is `path('start/', views.start_game, name='start')`. I tried to use `window.location.href = "{% url 'Chess_Django:start/' %}"`. But I got this error:
[image]

Right now I am able to access it using the absolute path. But I am just curious how to achieve it using Django template language. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try without trailing slash (since it's namespace):

```
window.location.href = "{% url 'Chess_Django:start' %}"
```

or even

```
window.location.href = "{% url 'start' %}"
```